# Why was the 11th Doctor flying the 10th’s TARDIS?

Tags: doctor-who

In *Day of The Doctor*, why was the 11<sup>th</sup> Doctor flying the 10th's TARDIS? They get in 10's TARDIS, but 11 starts flying it.

Comment: Same software, different case.

Answer (score 13):

The 11th Doctor appeared to the 10th through a time fissure:

> **10th Doctor**: Back, both of you, now! That's a time fissure. A tear in the fabric of reality. Anything could happen.

The 11th Doctor is the newest regeneration of the Doctor, and 10 believes that 11 should remember what's going on:

> **10th Doctor**: Okay, you used to be me, you've done all this before. What happens next?
>   **11th Doctor**: I don't remember.
>   **10th Doctor**: How can you forget this?
>   **11th Doctor**: Hey, hang on. It's not my fault. You're obviously not paying enough attention.

When the 3 Doctors get to the Tardis it starts having problems:

> **10th Doctor**: Ow! The desktop is glitching.
>   **War Doctor**: Three of us from different time zones. It's trying to compensate.
>   **11th Doctor**: Hey, look. The round things.
>   **10th Doctor**: I love the round things.
>   **11th Doctor**: What are the round things?
>   **10th Doctor**: No idea.
>   **11th Doctor**: Oh dear, the friction contrafibulator. Ha! There, stabilised. (The Tardis changes again.)
>   **10th Doctor**: Oh, you've redecorated. I don't like it.

11 stabilized the Tardis to his "desktop", 10 doesn't like it. It may be akin to going from one Linux distribution to another or from Windows 7 to Windows 10, everything is there but maybe not where you expect, so it made sense for 11 to pilot his "desktop".

**In Summary:**

- Eleven instigated the adventure when he met Ten through the time
  fissure.
- The fissure was happening to Eleven, not Ten who was a
  bystander  .
- Eleven was the furthest point in the Doctor's time line
  so he should have the best chance of remembering what is occurring  .
- The Tardis was set to Eleven's desktop.

---

Out of universe, Matt Smith was the incumbent Doctor, so he got to take the lead over David Tennant.

Comment: In-universe, wouldn't the time fissure be happening to the War Doctor?

Comment: @user24601 technically it happened to all of the Doctors, but from 10s perspective in Elizabethan England, 11 came through it.

Comment: That makes sense..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Plus, it does always compensate to the LATEST Doctor's incarnation (conviniently fitting with the out-of-universe reality, where the latest doctor should take the lead...)

I do like how they did give Hurt the stellar. Sort of. He was in and out-universe main character after all. He was hurting, a terrible choice thrusted upon him. And the moment was just that. A moment to make the right choice; to get help, to think it through and solve it.
Anyway, that last part was just poetic, not adding much to the answer :P.

Comment: Does this add anything to the existing answer? Your first paragraph is a point already made by NikolaiDante, and the second, while a nice bit of wordplay, doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Should I delete it?